# Code blocks workspace only builds active project?

Tags: codeblocks, workspace

I have the fallowing setup in code-blocks:

[image: CodeBlocks workspace with 2 projects in it, 3 files, 2 for "ProgramLibrary", and 1 for "Program"]

I have "Program" (the highlighted project) selected to depend on "ProgramLibrary" by doing

1. Right click "Program" and selecting "Properties..."
2. Under "Project Settings" selecting "Project's Dependancies..."
3. Checking "ProjectLibrary" in the box that appears.

I have saved the workspace. I can open it by double clicking it, and it'll appear with both projects open already. It will only compile the Active project. However, I can go through both projects and compile each individually for my desired goal.

According to [CodeBlocks.org](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=The_build_process_of_Code::Blocks)'s documentation, it should compile all projects contained in the workspace.

> Use the menu "Build->Build workspace" to build a workspace (i.e. all the projects contained in it).

I'm compiling the workspace with "Build->Build workspace", (as stated) and have also tried compiling by right clicking in explorer, with no difference.

Current directory tree is

```
\Project.workspace
\ProgramLibrary\
    \ProgramLibrary.cbp
    \ProgramLibrary.depend
    \ProgramLibrary.layout
    \ProgramLibrary.h
    \ProgramLibrary.cpp
\Program\
    \Program.cbp
    \Program.depend
    \Program.layout
    \Program.cpp
\dist\
    \ProgramLibrary.dll.a
    \ProgramLibrary.dll
    \Program.exe
```

And, to verify that both projects are in the workspace, here's the workspace file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<CodeBlocks_workspace_file>
    <Workspace title="Program">
        <Project filename="ProgramLibrary/ProgramLibrary.cbp" />
        <Project filename="Program/Program.cbp" active="1">
            <Depends filename="ProgramLibrary/ProgramLibrary.cbp" />
        </Project>
    </Workspace>
</CodeBlocks_workspace_file>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: Upgrade to CodeBlocks 12.11